# node.js and canvas, gameloop out out of sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, canvas

I am building multiplayer real-time space shooter game. At first i created only single player local version of the game to see how things can be done. Game was runing smoothly with stable 60 fps. I was happy with the core and performance so i started porting it for multi player version. As server for the game i use node.js.

I want every player to see the same "state" of game and have the same experience with the game so i decided to only pass player input to the server and let server calculate everything.

The question is, which method should be used for game loop on server side?

Server is calculating enemies position and enemies bullets. I used `setInterval` method:

```
setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        var enemy = enemies[i];
        enemy.move();
        enemy.fire();
    }
    io.emit('enemies', enemies);
}, 1000 / 60)
```

enemy move function is like this:

```
    this.move = function() {
        this.x += (this.movX - this.x) / this.speed;
        this.y += (this.movY - this.y) / this.speed;
    };
```

On the client side i run `requestAnimationFrame` loop:

```
socket.on('enemies', function(enemies) {
    self.enemies = enemies;
});
var run = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < self.enemies.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var enemy = self.enemies[i];
            if(enemy.alive) {

                for(var i = 0; i < enemy.primary_bullets_pool.length; i++) {
                    var bullet = enemy.primary_bullets_pool[i];
                    if(bullet.alive) {
                        self.context.fillStyle = 'red';
                        self.context.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.w, bullet.h);
                    }
                }

                self.context.drawImage(self.images[enemy.model], enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.w, enemy.h);
            }
        }(i));
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
};
```

Now the user experience is very bad. Enemies are "jumping" on the screen instead of move smoothly. I experimented with timing for interval. If put 10 ms instead of 1000 / 60 - it is going a little bit better but jittering still is visible. What is the right way to make it happen so every player can see enemies in the same position at any given time and move is done smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, it looks like you're updating enemy positions every "tick"- which, as you've noticed, will appear jittery if the server can't update their positions quickly enough.

Ideally, you don't want your server to have to emit position events for all enemies to all players constantly just to achieve smooth movement. That's a lot of overhead for something that ought to be handled entirely on the client.

What I advise is not updating an enemy's position on the client every "tick," but accepting a set of coordinates the enemy should be moving toward whenever an enemy begins moving (or begins moving in a different direction) and then animating that. This will get you the smoother experience you want.

Some of the answers on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50978/moving-a-sprite-towards-an-x-and-y-coordinate) from the GameDev Stack Exchange ought to point you in the right direction for implementing a "move toward" function.